# opening page to element with hash/pound in url

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, scrollto

For some reason my on page scroll works fine, linking to a div id.

But if I load the page with the hash in the url, it ignores the hash and opens at the top of the page.

My hash url looks like this:
`http://uk2.local/#customer-promise`

and the element i'm linking too like this:

`<section id="customer-promise"></section>`

I'm open to using jQuery for this to function and any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There's no reason to use jQuery or any javascript for this. It should work.. Is there any javascript on your page setting the scroll to 0? That might be breaking the native hash jumping functionality.

Comment: @yts nope, that's what's so confusing.

Comment: interesting... is that section#customer-promise in the html on page load or is it being added via javascript?

Comment: @yts it's pulled via a php includes. Strangly if i then highlight the url with the hash and hit enter whilst on the `uk2.local` page. The section shows at the top of the viewport.